# Android Job Service doesn't excute method from shared code in back ground

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created service to check notification from my own server.

It works fine when my app is running but it doesn't work that well when my app removed from recently. I made toast to check if my service stilling run or not, and the toast worked after I killed the application, but the method that checks server doesn't work in background.

I use xamarin forms and android service with android oreo installed in my emulator this my code

```
public class MyService : JobService
{
    private void DoWork()
    {
        try
        {
            Intent i =new Intent(this.ApplicationContext,typeof(MyReciver));
            i.SetAction("ezz");
            SendBroadcast(i);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            StopSelf();
        }

    }

    public override bool OnStartJob(JobParameters jobparams)
    {
        new Task(() =>
        {
        while (true)
            {
                DoWork();
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                JobFinished(jobparams, true);
            }
        }).Start();
        return true;

    }

    public override bool OnStopJob(JobParameters jobparams)
    {
        return true;

    }
}
```

And this is my receiver:

```
if (intent.Action == "ezz")
        {
            try
            {
                txtmod v = new txtmod();//to get the last id doesn't work in background
                string cc = v.readtxt();
                string bb = "Last id " + cc;
                Toast.MakeText(context, bb, ToastLength.Short).Show();//run in foreground and stil running in back ground
                PostReq post = new PostReq(1);//doesn't work in background
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

Comment: does `StopSelf()` method  shut down the service itself

Comment: yes and i comment it but the same result